Tree implementation with ext version 7.6 is throwing error in the console
I am trying to implement EXT tree grid with version 7.6. but tree.js dependency is not found in @sencha directory of node_module.
Code for tree grid implementation in ext js 
console error
Ext.define('App.view.tablet.organization.Browse', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Tree',
requires: [
    'Ext.data.TreeStore'
],

title: 'Tree in Grid',
width: 500,
height: 300,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
rootVisible: false,
store: Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [
            { text: "Node 1", leaf: true },
            { text: "Node 2", leaf: true },
            { text: "Node 3", expanded: true, children: [
                { text: "Child Node 1", leaf: true },
                { text: "Child Node 2", leaf: true }
            ]}
        ]
    }
}),
columns: [{
    xtype: 'treecolumn',
    text: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'text',
    flex: 1
}]

});

Error in console
bootstrap.js:1595
   GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@sencha/ext-modern/src/grid/Tree.js?_dc=1715779815777 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

